# Conditional Expectation for computing total goals

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation

Suppose Team A and Team B plays a soccer match. Team A is expected to score 1.58 goals at home while Team B is expected to concede 0.94 goals when away. On the other hand, Team B scores 1.28 goals when away and Team A concedes 0.40 goals at home. What is the total expected goals for the match?

Comment: It depends on the probability that team A plays at home.

Comment: Hi what if Team A plays at home?